# Android TextView not updating after setText

Tags: android

I have an app using multiple tabs. On one tab, I have a TextView where the displayed value does not update after .setText in one case. When I use Log.d with .getText it shows the correct value in the Log but the content of the TextView displayed remains blank.

My objective is to have a button on a tab that allows a user to select from the native Android Call History log (the same data we see in the Phone App call log) and then update a TextView on one of the tabs with the phone number associated with the selected call log item. I am using StartActivityForResult to get the phone number and that part seems to be working based on what I see with Log.d.

I have read quite a few posts on StackOverflow and some blogs resulting from Google searches on this issue but still cannot seem to make this work. They suggested using a runnable construct and alternatively the .PostInvalidate method on the TextView. Neither of these approaches have helped. The TextView still refuses to update for this particular scenario.

The weird thing is that I have other buttons on the same tab that use .setText for the same TextView and they work just fine. However, each of those does all its work in the main Class methods without doing a StartActivityForResult. All my Log.d points generate the expected results and show the values that I expect at each step listed below.

Here is the latest iteration of my code for consideration:

In my Class Constructor .OnCreate():

```
    t1 = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    Log.d("MyApp","First t1.toString: "+t1.toString());
```

In my onClick():

```
    CharSequence currentNumber = t1.getText();
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.button1:
        t1.setText(currentNumber + "1");            
        break;
    case R.id.button2:
        t1.setText(currentNumber + "2");
        break;
    case R.id.button3:
        t1.setText(currentNumber + "3");
        break;
    case R.id.CallLog:
        Log.i("MyApp", "Call Log Selected");
        Intent CallLogIntent = new Intent();
        CallLogIntent.setClass(Page2Activity.this, CallLogActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(CallLogIntent,3);
        break;
```

In my OnActivityResult():

```
    case 3:
        Log.d("MyApp", "Result Received");
        Log.d("MyApp", "Result: " + data.getStringExtra("NUMBER"));
        t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        Log.d("MyApp", "t1.toString: " + t1.toString());
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                t1.setText(data.getStringExtra("NUMBER"));
                Log.d("MyApp", "t1.getText before PostInvalidate: " + t1.getText());
                t1.postInvalidate();
                Log.d("MyApp", "t1.getText after PostInvalidate: " + t1.getText());
            }
        });
        break;
```

Here are the added logs

```
09-14 16:13:25.022 21154-21154/com.example.startactivityforresult D/MyApp: lv: android.widget.ListView{23598aa VFED.VC.. ......I. 0,0-0,0 #102000a android:id/list}

09-14 16:13:32.462 21154-21154/com.example.startactivityforresult D/MyApp: Position: 5 adapter: android.content.ContentResolver$CursorWrapperInner@c2012bd

09-14 16:13:32.462 21154-21154/com.example.startactivityforresult D/MyApp: tv2: (555) 555-1212

09-14 16:13:32.492 21154-21154/com.example.startactivityforresult D/MyApp: Result Code: -1

09-14 16:13:32.492 21154-21154/com.example.startactivityforresult D/MyApp: Request Code: 3

09-14 16:13:32.492 21154-21154/com.example.startactivityforresult D/MyApp: Result Received

09-14 16:13:32.492 21154-21154/com.example.startactivityforresult D/MyApp: Result: (555) 555-1212

09-14 16:13:32.492 21154-21154/com.example.startactivityforresult D/MyApp: t1.toString: android.widget.TextView{d87d033 V.ED..... ......ID 16,16-1344,213 #7f0d0058 app:id/textView1}

09-14 16:13:32.492 21154-21154/com.example.startactivityforresult D/MyApp: t1.getText: (555) 555-1212

09-14 16:13:32.542 21154-21154/com.example.startactivityforresult D/MyApp: First t1.toString: android.widget.TextView{9504d57 V.ED..... ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f0d0058 app:id/textView1}
```

Comment: remove
 t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1); from OnActivityResult():

Comment: Why do you need the Handler?

Comment: where you are setting value inside **NUMBER** intent?

Comment: @Vishal - tried it... nothing changed in performance though. Thanks for helping me realize I don't need it.

Comment: @cricket_007 - I started without it but that did not work. Found the recommendation in a blog and on another similar thread here on StackExchange recommending that any updates to the UI be run inside a handler to ensure that it is run on the main thread of the UI. Seemed strange to me but got some upchecks from others so gave it a try.

Comment: @Rahul - I set the value of NUMBER in my class that handles the StartActivityForResult. That class returns the value as an Extra which I then access with my intention to update the TextView in the UI. It is strange to me because when I do .getText on it after I attempt the update, Log.d shows the correct value but the UI continues to show blank in the TextView.

Comment: `onActivityResult` is already on the UI thread, so you shouldn't need it

Comment: @cricket_007 - I agree. Tested and confirmed without the handler as suggested with the code sample Vishal provided but still no update visible on the TextView. Thoughts?

Comment: Did you check whether textColor is different from the background color?

Comment: So, you removed the extra `findViewById`? Could you [edit] to indeed show that your Logs are what you expect?

Comment: @cricket_007: Here are the logs...

Comment: That last line - `First t1.toString` that is from `onCreate`, yes? It might be that your activity is being finished, then restarting, thereby causing `onCreate` to be triggered again after `startActivityForResult`

Comment: @Mobile Developer: Yes. Confirmed that the text color and background color are not the same. Good thought though.

Comment: @cricket_007: I think you are on to something here. Yes, that log entry is generated during the OnCreate process. Seems like there must be something I don't understand about the lifecycle of this thing. Now we are getting somewhere though. Thoughts?

Comment: I mean, the TextView would have whatever default value it had when the Activity started, as if it was the first time. Is that another way to describe "not changing"?

Comment: @cricket_007: I added Log.d for each state... onCreate, onStart, onRestart, onResume, onPause, onStop, onDestroy to see what is happening. Nothing on any of them except onCreate. Exactly as cricket_007 suspected! Not sure why it is working this way. I welcome additional advice and think I will go research how to save the state in my OnActivityResult and then check for saved state during onCreate to restore the info. Not sure how to do this but figure there must be a way. Thanks to all for your suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

**replace**

```
case 3:

    Log.d("MyApp", "Result Received");
    Log.d("MyApp", "Result: " + data.getStringExtra("NUMBER"));
    Log.d("MyApp", "t1.toString: " + t1.toString());

    t1.setText(data.getStringExtra("NUMBER"));
    Log.d("MyApp", "t1.getText before PostInvalidate: " + t1.getText());

    break;
```

Comment: Thanks Vishal. This did not work though. The expected values are appearing in the Log.d results so this is a much simpler way to get to the same spot that I was with my more complex approach shown above. The UI is still showing blank for the TextView where I am expecting to see the value contained in NUMBER.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all who commented! It turned out that onCreate was being called everytime that onActivityResult is completed just as 007 suspected. I wound up using a SharedPreference setting as a semaphore using a Boolean and another SharedPreference setting of String type to store the value at the end of the OnActivityResult and then checking it during the OnCreate process. The basic flow goes like this:

OnCreate()

If semaphore is true:
    Retrieve the SharedPreference String value and do a putText in to the TextView.
    Set the semaphore to false.
  Do all the rest of the stuff I want to do in the OnCreate.

OnActivityResult()

Get the value from the helper class.
  Store the value in the SharedPreference String.
  Set the semaphore to true.